# nosetests: error: no such option: --profile-restrict

Tags: nose, python-2to3

I am migrating from python2 to python3 and facing problems with migrating nosetests.
When I used python2 I ran my tests with following command:

```
nosetests --stop --verbose --with-profile --profile-restrict='tests.py' --nocapture tests.py
```

Now I run my tests with:

```
nosetests --stop --verbose --with-cprofile --profile-restrict='tests.py' --nocapture tests.py
```

and have error `nosetests: error: no such option: --profile-restrict`.
What is the problem and how to fix it?